# Broken screen, need to boot to original firmware

Tags: motorola-droid-razr, safe-mode, broken-screen

This is kind of an odd question, but I have a Razr with a broken screen which has safestrap 2.x (maybe .10) installed and CM10 currently booted up, using VNC/ADB/LOTS of patience, I managed to backup all my information in the CM10 partition.

However, I need to boot to the original firmware (the other partition), however since the screen is broken I can't see safestrap windows to do so, **what I'm asking for is if someone has screenshots of the safestrap windows** that enable me to **blindly** navigate (since the physical buttons work) through the screens in order to boot to the original firmware, then I will repeat the ADB/VNC process to remove the safestrap traces so I can send it to Motorola.

Comment: Please check out my answer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36860/12677), which could be useful for you. Originally this was going to be an answer to your question, but I did not post it here because it does not respond exactly to what you're asking.

Comment: Does that work with safestrap? I mean can I visualize the safestrap/recovery screen? o.0

Comment: I'm not sure about it: also that's why I didn't post that as an answer here. Anyway you could try that to see if it works for you.