# My screen got broken, how to see on the computer what I'm doing in my device?

Tags: usb, screen, screenshots, broken-screen

My Android device screen got broken and I can't see what I'm doing. That's the only wrong thing with my device, the rest is apparently working OK. **Is there any way to send my device screen to my computer?**
I don't want to work blindly anymore!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to continue working blindly, you can use **Droid@Screen**: it shows the screen of a real or emulated Android device on a computer running Windows, Mac OS or Linux.

[image]

**Droid@Screen** is a stand-alone Java Swing GUI application that shows the screen of an Android device on a computer. Its author says that its typical usage is showing an app demo or during training, but it also fits your case.

In order to use it, you need the following to be installed in your computer:

- *Java* 6 (at least)
- *Android SDK*, installed and configured.
- *Environment variable* `ANDROID_HOME` (or `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`) pointing to the Android SDK installation directory. (Optional)
- *USB driver* for the target Android device installed.

**Note:** *USB Debugging must be enabled* on your device. (Thanks @JasonC for the heads up)

I have been using it with my Galaxy Nexus and I must say that despite a little *lag* between what happens in the phone and what is displayed in the computer screen (2-4 s), it does what it says. You **don't** even need to be rooted for that!

You can download it from the [author's site](http://droid-at-screen.org/), where you also can watch a complete video and text instructions about its installation and usage.

Comment: You have to enable USB debugging for it to work, which means its useless if debugging was disabled when you broke your screen, because the Android folks failed to make the connection that everything you'd want to do with a broken screen requires a working screen to change that one setting.

Comment: It is possible to enable developer mode and usb debugging via connecting a USB keyboard with adapter to the phone and sending a carefully planned set of keystrokes. Plan that set of keystrokes with an a phone of the same manufacturer and OS version. For example, down, down, ENTER will get you to the app chooser menu. Use arrow keys to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

If your device has an HDMIport, you can connect that to a display with HDMI port. There are programs, like Droid@Screen, as Dan said, that can cast the device's video output to a PC over the USB connection.

Comment: I improved the wording of your answer a bit, Daniel. Hope you don't mind