# use android phone with broken screen

Tags: touchscreen, remote-control, broken-screen

My phone screen has been broken, I have root access and my usb debugmode is on. when i connect my phone to Moborobo, moborobo shows the screen shot on my phone, is there any way to touch my phone screen with pc ? something like real remote that give me this chance to use my mouse for accessing my phone ?

Comment: U can also look at that answer (Y)

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36860/my-screen-got-broken-how-to-see-on-the-computer-what-im-doing-in-my-device

Answer (score 0):

try MyPhoneExplorer at www.fjsoft.at
it provides you access like a remote does to a tv, and you can use the mouse on your pc as a touch control for android.
its not a smooth experience but workable.
you can also use to back up device data as well
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Samsung Note 2 , so if u want to recover data ( like sms and contacts ) you should use ***coolmuster***

http://www.coolmuster.com/android/recover-data-from-broken-samsung-phone.html

good luck ;)