# How to extract data from Samsung S5 with broken screen+digitizer?

Tags: usb, data-recovery, photos, file-transfer, broken-screen

I need to extract the photos from the internal memory of my Samsung S5. I've downloaded some software called dr.fone which shows me previews of my files (i think by downloading software onto the phone) so it must be possible but it is expensive for the full version. Are there any free apps which I can find to do this? (All search results give expensive heavily SEOed apps!

Comment: USB attached to your computer can generally find those files worth copying. I added relevant tags USB and file-transfer. Investigate procedure and techniques by clicking those tags retrieving associated questions and answers.

Comment: @wbogacz when I connect my phone to my PC it just shows the phone model as an icon with a Drive letter but it is an empty folder

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please check the data-recovery section of our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info). As this issue already has come up here umpteen times, we already have that covered more than once. (Note: many of our tags have such useful wikis attached, always worth checking ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My screen got broken, how to see on the computer what I'm doing in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36860/my-screen-got-broken-how-to-see-on-the-computer-what-im-doing-in-my-device)

Answer (score 0):

Actually firstly when you connect your phone to pc it will show your phone icon and drive but it will empty until you will unlock your phone and that you can't do.

if you have enabled usb debugging than you can backup your files via adb.
use following adb command after connecting to adb terminal and listing your device is adb.
type:-

"`adb pull /storage/sdcard0/ C:\to_folder_where_you_want_t0_copy`"

Have a great day